# Modulo 2 on sum of squares giving odd prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Basically while proving sum of squares can never be a odd prime modulo 4, for example in the following congruence
$$x^2+y^2\equiv11(\text{mod}\space4)$$
and we go on to show that squares reduced modulo 4
$$x^2\equiv0\space \text{or} \space 1(\text{mod}\space 4) $$
and hence it follows that under congruence the addition of $0$ or $1$ never be $3$ 
.

My question if what if we reduce modulo 2

$$x^2+y^2\equiv11(\text{mod}\space2)$$
Now $0$ or $1$ can add to $1$ under modulo 2.

Maybe I have misunderstood the concept. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Um.... $4$ is not equal to $2$.  Why would you expect the results for $4$ to be the same as the results for $2$?  $x^2 + y^2$ can not be an odd prime modulo over $4$.  But it can be an odd prime modulo over $2$ (or over $3$ ... or $5$ .... or $6$...) That is because $4$ and $2$ are different numbers (as are $3$ and $4$... or $5$ and $4$ .... or $6$ and $4$....

Comment: $3 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ so $x^2 + y^2 \equiv p \mod 2$ means $p \equiv 1 \mod 2$ which means *EITHER* $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ which is possible.  Or $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ which is not.  So... no contradiction, no problem...

Answer (score 2):

Because $11\equiv 1\bmod 2$ you are asking about $x^2+y^2\equiv 1\bmod 2$. This is perfectly possible, as $x=1,y=2$ show.

Comment: But doesn't that mean we have integral solutions to $x^2+y^2=11$. Which is not possible?

Comment: No, since considering modulo $4$ still gives a contradiction, even though modulo $2$ does not give a contradiction. In other words, one contradiction is enough.

Comment: Oh. So iff we are able to find a certain modulo that gives a contradiction, only then would it become an impossibility?

Comment: What if the modulo is a very large prime?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=n$ would be an impossibility if and only if Fermat's conditions are satisfied - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem).

Comment: No.  It means you have integeral solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = 11 + 2k$.  Is could be fine.  For example $k = 7; x=3; y = 4$.  What you can't have is integral solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = 11 + 4k$.  What this means is if $x^2 + y^2 =11 + 2k$ then we know that $k$ must be odd. ... which is fine.  We have solutions for $k = 7, 17, 35, etc.$.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark(I)**:

- If $z=2k$; then $z^2=4k^2 \overset{4}{\equiv} 0$.
- If $z=2k+1$; then $z^2=4k^2+4k+1 \overset{4}{\equiv} 1$.

---

**Remark(II)**: 
We have the following possibilities for $x^2+y^2$ module $4$:

- $0+0=0$.
- $0+1=1$.
- $1+0=1$.
- $1+1=2$.

So $x^2+y^2 \overset{4}{\equiv} 11 \overset{4}{\equiv} 3$ is impossible.

---

---

**Remark(III)**:

- If $z=2k$; then $z^2=4k^2 \overset{2}{\equiv} 0$.
- If $z=2k+1$; then $z^2=4k^2+4k+1 \overset{2}{\equiv} 1$.

---

**Remark(IV)**: 
We have the following possibilities for $x^2+y^2$ module $4$:

- $0+0=0$.
- $0+1=1$.
- $1+0=1$.
- $1+1=2 \overset{2}{\equiv} 0$.

So the case $x^2+y^2 \overset{2}{\equiv} 3 \overset{2}{\equiv} 1$ is possible; 
by **Remark(III)** and **Remark(IV)** it only suffices 
to let one of the $x$ and $y$ to be odd integer and 
the the otherone to be even integer.